# Div elements moving in opposite directions causes scroll to jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, transform, translate

I am creating a scroll effect that makes each image move in the opposite direction on scroll. I have achieved this but the scroll becomes less smooth and more jittery the more you scroll.

I believe it is because I am constantly getting the distance from the top of the viewport for each image (item). Does anyone know how to get around this?

```
var $animatedEls = $(".block-inner");

      $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var offset = 0;

        // Loop through each image (.block-inner)
        $.each($animatedEls, function(i, item) {

            // Get offset for each .inner-block
            offset = $(item).offset().top - scrollTop;

            console.log(i+') '+offset);

            // Apply to every second item
            if (i % 2) {
                $(item).css("transform","translateY(-" +  (offset/20)  + "px)");
            } else {
                $(item).css("transform","translateY(" +  (offset/20)  + "px)");
            }
        });

});
```

Fiddle Added: https://jsfiddle.net/2bos5oqh/4/

Comment: make a jsfiddle to duplicate the problem. hard to know what you mean when you say you want parallax and then post an example of a website that doesn't use parallax.

Comment: Fiddle added https://jsfiddle.net/2bos5oqh/4/ although seems be scrolling pretty smooth on the jsfiddle site

Comment: would seem to me that the jittery scroll would be due to the olther elements on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the animation have an animation-duration? If so, chances are that the scroll event is firing multiple times before a single update has completed.

Try debouncing the function
https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: No it doesn't have an animation-duration it just fires on page scroll